# Keep dummy clocks in SCLK (SPI)

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm using ESP32 on VSPI in a half-duplex manner with a slave device.

I wish to first send the device a standard SPI transaction, and right after that to keep clocking out dummy pulses in the same VSPI interface (clocking VSPICLK pin with same frequency, with zeros on VSPID).

I managed to send the transaction itself, but I don't find the right way to keep the dummy clocks. Important to mention that the dummy pulses shouldn't block the code so I can handle other tasks.

Any thoughts?

**Update:**

Getting closer by calling a simple write bytes method

```
/**
 * @param data uint8_t *
 * @param size uint32_t
 */
void SPIClass::writeBytes(const uint8_t * data, uint32_t size)
{
    if(_inTransaction){
        return spiWriteNL(_spi, data, size);
    }
    spiSimpleTransaction(_spi);
    spiWriteNL(_spi, data, size);
    spiEndTransaction(_spi);
}
```

But this one blocks...

**Previously:**

I've tries to send empty bytes in a normal SPI transaction but this is a blocking method and got some lags between bytes (you can see it in the VSCLK blue channel).

[dummy clocks with lags, and blocking code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDW1H.png)

```
void write(uint8_t data)
{
    noInterrupts();


    // Working transaction to the device
    // _spi_dev is an SPIClass*
    _spi_dev->beginTransaction();
    _spi_dev->transfer(data);
    _spi_dev->endTransaction();
    delayMicroseconds(10); // Required delay by the slave device to latch the command


    // naively sending dummy bytes - a blocking call
    _spi_dev->beginTransaction();
    for (uint8_t n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
        for (int8_t c = 10; c > 0; c--) _spi_dev->transfer(0x0);
    }
    _spi_dev->endTransaction();
  
    interrupts();
}
```

This code:

```
_spi_dev->transfer(data);
```

ends up with this:

```
uint8_t spiTransferByte(spi_t * spi, uint8_t data)
{
    if(!spi) {
        return 0;
    }
    SPI_MUTEX_LOCK();
    spi->dev->mosi_dlen.usr_mosi_dbitlen = 7;
    spi->dev->miso_dlen.usr_miso_dbitlen = 7;
    spi->dev->data_buf[0] = data;
#if CONFIG_IDF_TARGET_ESP32C3
    spi->dev->cmd.update = 1;
    while (spi->dev->cmd.update);
#endif
    spi->dev->cmd.usr = 1;
    while(spi->dev->cmd.usr);
    data = spi->dev->data_buf[0] & 0xFF;
    SPI_MUTEX_UNLOCK();
    return data;
}
```

In Addition this one:

```
_spi_dev->beginTransaction();
```

With this:

```
void SPIClass::beginTransaction(SPISettings settings)
{
    //check if last freq changed
    uint32_t cdiv = spiGetClockDiv(_spi);
    if(_freq != settings._clock || _div != cdiv) {
        _freq = settings._clock;
        _div = spiFrequencyToClockDiv(_freq);
    }
    spiTransaction(_spi, _div, settings._dataMode, settings._bitOrder);
    _inTransaction = true;
}
```

Comment: Without your code, we don't know what you actually did.

Comment: Right... Updated

Comment: How many bytes you trying to read from the slave? in order to get the data, you need an buf to capture the data you received like `buf[i++] _spi_dev->transfer(0x00);`.

Comment: BTW, where is your code for controlling Chip Select (CS or SS) signal?

Comment: Because it's half-duplex I don't care about the returned MISO byte received from the slave.